# How to write an efficient evaluation function in a chess game? (Minimax algo used)

Tags: python, evaluation, chess, minimax, minmax

I have developed a chess system in python and have implemented the minimax algorithm. http://www.naftaliharris.com/blog/chess

However, the evaluation function I have written is very weak. I wanted to know if there are any existing functions or algorithms available for the same.

Comment: yeah. couldn't find any open source code available.

Comment: You can find quite a lot of info here https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Yes, check alpha-beta pruning on that site - much more efficient.